# Calling MYSQL CREATE VIEW using php code?

Tags: php, mysql, view

need some enlightment here, and this is my first post here.

I would like to call and use my previously created mysql view using php... is it possible?
or in another words,
i'm wondering....can we OR how do we call mysql view, that we already created using php? to reduce long query coding

standard generic codes as follow :

```
$sql= " SELECT shipping.tarrif1, city.city_name
         FROM shipping JOIN city
   ON shipping.id_city = city.id_city";
$db->QueryArray($sql);   

while ($row = $db->Row()) {
echo $row->city_name. " - " . $row->tarrif1 . "<br />\n"; 
}
```

now for the MYSQL VIEWS :

```
$sql= " CREATE VIEW shipsumarry AS SELECT shipping.tarrif1, city.city_name
         FROM shipping JOIN city
   ON shipping.id_city = city.id_city";
```

Pure MYSQL command :

```
query: SELECT * FROM shipsummary
```

IN PHP :

```
 $sql = i'm badly stuck here...please help
```

How do we access it using php.

thanks before

Addition 1:

ok... let me rewrite the example :

```
$sql1= " CREATE VIEW shipsumarry AS SELECT shipping.tarrif1, city.city_name
         FROM shipping JOIN city
   ON shipping.id_city = city.id_city";
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM shipsummary";
$db->QueryArray($sql2);
```

$sql2 can not see shipsummary VIEW, coz it's already in a different var

how to utilise and then execute $sql1 ? & $sql2?

Comment: Did you actually execute the `CREATE VIEW` statement? I only see it assigned to the variable `$sql`.  And you aren't recreating it on each pageload, are you?

Comment: A view ideally acts exactly like a table. So you query it in PHP as if it were a table. If this isn't working, please edit your post to include the error message you receive when you try the code Michael posted.

Comment: @Michael : i haven't executed it yet, coz i'm stuck after assigned it....

Comment: @derobert : yes, you're right, it shows blank screen, and php error reporting already set to all

Comment: @BayuSetiawan: Check your web server error logs, then. Or wherever you've set your PHP logging to go. Its generating an error, you just need to figure out how to see it. (But, I'm guessing, its a permission error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process is the same in PHP - a MySQL view is seen by the client (PHP) as a regular table, so querying it as

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shipsummary");

// Or for whatever framework you're using:
$db->QueryArray("SELECT * FROM shipsummary");
```

should work correctly.  If it does not work correctly, the MySQL user with which you are accessing the view may have broken permissions. (Seems unlikely though).

**UPDATE**

After you edited your question, I can see the problem quite clearly.

```
$sql1= " CREATE VIEW shipsumarry AS SELECT shipping.tarrif1, city.city_name
         FROM shipping JOIN city
   ON shipping.id_city = city.id_city";
$sql2= "SELECT * FROM shipsummary";

// Here, you need to execute $sql1 before $sql2 is useful.
$db->QueryArray($sql1);
// Now execute $sql2
$db->QueryArray($sql2);
```

We don't know what database class or framework you are using, but if there is a comparable method to `QueryArray()` that doesn't return a result set, but just executes a statement, use it to create the view instead.

### Now, all that being said...

Unless the definition of the view must change every time this code executes, and unless you have a reason to then `DROP VIEW shipsummary` at the end of this script's execution each time, it makes far, far, far, far .... more sense to simply create the view in the database, where it will stay forever, rather than to keep re-creating it with PHP.  Views, once created, stay created.

Don't think of them as a temporary query time/code saver.  Create the views you will need **ONCE** in your database (using PHPMyAdmin or mysql CLI, or however you created your tables), and access them with PHP.

Comment: Yeah i thought about the permissions too, but most of the time it's on the creation process that you are missing permissions not on the read portion...

Comment: i already checked the mysql privileges, and everything is fully checked, the main problem is as i have already made the 1st php variable that consist "CREATE VIEW" but the VIEW is visible only to the 1st php variable but not to the 2nd php variable, in other word i would like to call it like this : $db->QueryArray($2nd var that consist "SELECT * FROM shipsummary") this "shipsummary" not visible to 2nd var.. do i have to refactor my php dbquery class?

Comment: @BayuSetiawan Store them into separate variables. No need to re-use `$sql` over and over. Store the view creation into a variable, execute it to create the view, then execute queries against it with future `QueryArraY()` calls.

Comment: @BayuSetiawan See additions and notes above.

Comment: @Michael : thanks for ur latest reply..but it's not working Michael, coz the QueryArray() returned array result already, should i make the statement builder function inside db class? gimme example with this statement : how to call "shipsummary" view, after we created and assigned it in $sql1, because we can't extract the "shipsummary" view in sql1?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just send that

```
SELECT * FROM shipsummary
```

To mysql query, it should work, unless i'm not understanding your question...